# Installer Won't Accept File Path With Space

Tags: windows-7, installation, filepath

I'm trying to install an application in Windows 7, and when I specify a installation path with a space (Like "Program Files"), I get an error. I've tried excluding the space, putting the path in quotation marks, and using a "?" for a space.

Is there some kind of workaround?

EDIT: If I remove the space, it will work initially, but fails when it attempts to write files to that location.

Comment: Which installer utility are you using to package your application?  InstallShield?

Comment: The short name for `Program Files` is `C:\PROGRA~1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about **Program%Files**? I haven't tested it - let me know if it works or not :)

Comment: Damn, forgot about that. I'm sure that will work. (Confirmed, does work)